# Upsample timeseries in pandas with interpolation

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation

I have a

```
import pandas as pd
index = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=9, freq='0.9S')
series = pd.Series(range(9), index=index)

>>> series
2000-01-01 00:00:00.000    0
2000-01-01 00:00:00.900    1
2000-01-01 00:00:01.800    2
2000-01-01 00:00:02.700    3
2000-01-01 00:00:03.600    4
2000-01-01 00:00:04.500    5
2000-01-01 00:00:05.400    6
2000-01-01 00:00:06.300    7
2000-01-01 00:00:07.200    8
Freq: 900L, dtype: int64
```

Now I get

```
>>> series.resample(rule='0.5S').head(100)
2000-01-01 00:00:00.000    0.0
2000-01-01 00:00:00.500    1.0
2000-01-01 00:00:01.000    NaN
2000-01-01 00:00:01.500    2.0
2000-01-01 00:00:02.000    NaN
2000-01-01 00:00:02.500    3.0
2000-01-01 00:00:03.000    NaN
2000-01-01 00:00:03.500    4.0
2000-01-01 00:00:04.000    NaN
2000-01-01 00:00:04.500    5.0
2000-01-01 00:00:05.000    6.0
2000-01-01 00:00:05.500    NaN
2000-01-01 00:00:06.000    7.0
2000-01-01 00:00:06.500    NaN
2000-01-01 00:00:07.000    8.0
Freq: 500L, dtype: float64
```

as I would expect, but I get

```
>>> series.resample(rule='0.5S').interpolate(method='linear')
2000-01-01 00:00:00.000    0.000000
2000-01-01 00:00:00.500    0.555556
2000-01-01 00:00:01.000    1.111111
2000-01-01 00:00:01.500    1.666667
2000-01-01 00:00:02.000    2.222222
2000-01-01 00:00:02.500    2.777778
2000-01-01 00:00:03.000    3.333333
2000-01-01 00:00:03.500    3.888889
2000-01-01 00:00:04.000    4.444444
2000-01-01 00:00:04.500    5.000000
2000-01-01 00:00:05.000    5.000000
2000-01-01 00:00:05.500    5.000000
2000-01-01 00:00:06.000    5.000000
2000-01-01 00:00:06.500    5.000000
2000-01-01 00:00:07.000    5.000000
Freq: 500L, dtype: float64
```

where I would have expected that the last value is still 8.0 and still 7.0 for the timestamp with 6.5 secondss. What's up with that?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Maybe a bug? When i change the original sample frequency to 0.99, i get only zeros after interpolation

Comment: @Bharathshetty: As I wrote: the last value should be 8.0.

Comment: @FranzForstmayr: That does not sound correct either...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A way of getting this at least partially right (for real data, the results are not great, I had better success with [scipy's interp1d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html)) is to use `mean()` in between the methods:

```
>>> series.resample(rule='0.5S').mean().interpolate(method='linear')
2000-01-01 00:00:00.000    0.0
2000-01-01 00:00:00.500    1.0
2000-01-01 00:00:01.000    1.5
2000-01-01 00:00:01.500    2.0
2000-01-01 00:00:02.000    2.5
2000-01-01 00:00:02.500    3.0
2000-01-01 00:00:03.000    3.5
2000-01-01 00:00:03.500    4.0
2000-01-01 00:00:04.000    4.5
2000-01-01 00:00:04.500    5.0
2000-01-01 00:00:05.000    6.0
2000-01-01 00:00:05.500    6.5
2000-01-01 00:00:06.000    7.0
2000-01-01 00:00:06.500    7.5
2000-01-01 00:00:07.000    8.0
Freq: 500L, dtype: float64
```